# Cannot connect to raspberry pi database

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi

Just put my raspberry pi to use by putting a mysql server on it with phpmyadmin and I can connect fine using the web tool but I cannot get c# to connect to it, all I get as a error message is unable to connect to any of the mysql hosts :(

Here is my c# Code:

```cs
MySqlConnection sq = new MySqlConnection();
sq.ConnectionString = "Server = 192.168.0.247; Port = 3318; Database = MailTest; Uid = RPI; Pwd = mypassword;";

try
{
  sq.Open();
  MessageBox.Show("Success");
  sq.Clone();
}
catch(Exception s)
{                
  MessageBox.Show("Error   " + s.ToString() );
}
```

The port is set to 3318 in the my.cnf file! And here is my phpmyadmin privileges tab:
[image: User is RPI and password IS correct]

The error comes up pretty much instantly so is it even trying to connect?
The pc i'm trying to connect from is on the exact same network connected to a ethernet switch the raspberry pi is also connected to! The ip adress in my.cnf is set to 127.0.0.1

I don't know why it's not connecting...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: just because the DB is running on a port doesn't mean it's accessible from everywhere. it'd have to be bound to the IP:port, or *:port, and that port has to be open to the outside world as well...